# Why does Firefox consistently fail to resolve new tabs from right click or crash upon tab open?

Tags: wireless-networking, firefox, security, tabs, vulnerabilities

I have been using Firefox ESR packed to a portable application in Linux for some time. Older versions, even as little as .1 or .2 versions old, are so unstable as to be inoperable. I typically use a few plugins, particularly NoScript and uBlock Origin, and connect exclusively over public wifi dhcp connections.

Even the latest versions, with or without plugins installed, often fails to open new tabs using the right click and resolve their URL. At worst, new tabs crash the entire browser, which shuts immediately.

I also tried this with Firefox vanilla portable, and Firefox vanilla, rather than packed to portable folder, replete with .mozilla profile with the same result. I also altered the Firejail profile, which I regularly use with Firefox, assuming perhaps the rlimits set for the browser were too small, but this added no stability.

Running Firefox from terminal showed the following at crashtime on one occasion:

```
[GFX1-]: Receive IPC close with reason=AbnormalShutdown
[GFX1-]: Receive IPC close with reason=AbnormalShutdown
[Child 20465, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error (3): Connection reset by peer: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 358
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
[Child 20510, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error (3): Connection reset by peer: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 358
Exiting due to channel error.
```

NoScript has been seen to throw cross-site scripting attack warnings, but not reliably or exclusively.

Why is Firefox peculiarly subject to tab instability or attacks? Why do new tabs fail to resolve, or even close the browser?

Note that I am unable to respond to comments in new account.

Comment: The exact POSIX line error is given here; I'm surprised no one can answer; perhaps this is a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: However, further to the question, I will try strace and ltrace to establish system calls (glibc) and lib calls, and any errno, at crash time. POSIX error suggests a system call problem.

Comment: First, however, I will try the various versions on a standard Live platform to establish whether the issue is build-specific, distro-based or the FF itself.